# How to encode data for use in Charm's attribute based encryption?

Tags: python, cryptography, charm-crypto

I'm using Charm Crypto from Github. I'd like to use the attribute based encryption algorithms. The test code works fine, however, it uses a random message generated from PairingGroup. How do I use my own data for encryption?

```
>>> group = PairingGroup('SS512', secparam=512)
>>> msg = group.random(GT)
```

The PairingGroup has encode/decode methods, but they are not implemented. I just want to try this with "Hello world!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this class under  charm/charm/test/toolbox/symcrypto_test.py

```
class SymmetricCryptoAbstractionTest(unittest.TestCase):

def testAESCBC(self):
    self.MsgtestAESCBC(b"hello world")

def testAESCBCLong(self):
    self.MsgtestAESCBC(b"Lots of people working in cryptography have no deep \
   concern with real application issues. They are trying to discover things \
    clever enough to write papers about -- Whitfield Diffie.")

def testAESCBC_Seperate(self):
    self.MsgTestAESCBCSeperate(b"Lots of people working in cryptography have no deep \
    concern with real application issues. They are trying to discover things \
    clever enough to write papers about -- Whitfield Diffie.")

def MsgtestAESCBC(self,msg):
    groupObj = PairingGroup('SS512')
    a =  SymmetricCryptoAbstraction(sha1(groupObj.random(GT)))
    ct = a.encrypt(msg)
    dmsg = a.decrypt(ct);
    assert msg == dmsg , 'o: =>%s\nm: =>%s' % (msg, dmsg)

def MsgTestAESCBCSeperate(self,msg):
    groupObj = PairingGroup('SS512')
    ran = groupObj.random(GT)
    a =  SymmetricCryptoAbstraction(sha1(ran))
    ct = a.encrypt(msg)        
    b =  SymmetricCryptoAbstraction(sha1(ran))
    dmsg = b.decrypt(ct);
    assert msg == dmsg , 'o: =>%s\nm: =>%s' % (msg, dmsg)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I found abenc_adapt_hybrid.py in charm/charm/adapters/ that has similar code.